# How Can I run a bat file simultaneously with the vbs script running from same bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, command-prompt

How can I run a bat file simultaneously with the vbs script running from same bat file.
ie., can I input data into the cmd and the vbs file is also open along with it.
I am planning to make an unclosable vbs file but I want the bat file to be running with it too.
for example,

```
<BR>
@ECHO off<BR>
color FC<BR>
cls
<BR>
:start<BR>
ECHO.<BR>
ECHO 1. Hello there is no escape from me.<BR>
ECHO 2. Well come to hell.<BR>
ECHO 3. Bye-Bye.<BR>
C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe "C:\Users\user\Desktop\bat files\hahaha.vbs"<BR>

set choice=<BR>
set /p choice=Type any number between 1-3 from above choices to escape my wrath.<BR>
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%<BR>
if '%choice%'=='1' goto hello<BR>
if '%choice%'=='2' goto bye<BR>
if '%choice%'=='3' goto test<BR>
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again<BR>
ECHO.<BR>
goto start<BR>
:hello<BR>
c:\windows\system32\shutdown -s -f -t 10 -c "Deleting all your data!"<BR>
goto end<BR>
:bye<BR>
ECHO woah<BR>
goto end<BR>
:test<BR>
c:\windows\system32\shutdown /h <BR>
goto end<BR>
:end<BR>
PAUSE<BR>
<BR><BR><BR>
```

so now tell me that can hahaha.vbs(which is a infinte running loop) run along with the bat file where user can input choices into the bat file
so its like "ooh I cant close the vbs file so let me give my choice in the bat file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I think the [`START`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/start.php) command may be what you're looking for.  This allows a process to be started from a batch file, but the batch file will continue executing more commands, instead of waiting for that command to finish.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create the vbs file in the bat you can use this

```
echo do > test.txt
echo msgbox"hi" >> test.txt
echo loop >> test.txt
ren test.txt test.vbs
start test.vbs
pause 
del test .vbs
```

this creates an infinite loop of text windows, but you can put whatever in there, it wont have the "wscript.echo" in the .vbs

Answer (score 0):

e.g.

test.bat:

```
start wscript test.vbs

echo "hi there"
```