# Merging files of separate

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, cmd, command-prompt

How to save VBS and CMD files into one file? That could cowork? I know there is a VBS and Batch command that run separate files. Of course I could place VBS and CMD separately, but this could result hijacking attempts, which even I could make within 2 minutes.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run("msg * Hi LOL")
```

Answer is yes; and its listed above. It worked, now. The problem is, that VBS file, executes the command and runs for it, it doesn't wait for input.

After an edit while writing this, I tested script, and it works barely with other commands.
Is there possibility to make something like:

```
BATCH script start
BATCH commands
BATCH script end
VBS script start
VBS commands
VBS script end
```

**edit note:**
[How Can I run a bat file simultaneously with the vbs script running from same bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889383/how-can-i-run-a-bat-file-simultaneously-with-the-vbs-script-running-from-same-ba?rq=1)

My answer isn't related to this one. This answer wants place all underneath .bat file. I am open for any type of language that doesn't require installation on Windows.

**Total destination:** Being able to use both Batch and VBS commands in one exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=6 delims=" %%i IN (%0) DO @echo %%i >>"%temp%\tmp010.vbs"
cscript "%temp%\tmp010.vbs"
del "%temp%\tmp010.vbs"
pause

goto :eof
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
ie.AddressBar = 0 
ie.Visible = 1 
ie.ToolBar = 0 
ie.StatusBar = 0 
ie.Left = 400 
ie.Top = 100 
ie.Width = 800 
ie.Height = 900 
ie.Navigate2 "http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista?tab=question&status=all"
```

Comment: Absolutly. The for command strips out the batch commands leaving a vbs file. This achieves a bat and vbs file in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found

http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=103686.0

Who coulda thought, the easiest queries get most matches.